# Java JPanel default double buffering doesn't seem to get rid of Choppy movement

Tags: java, swing, game-loop, double-buffering

I've been working on a simple 2D Java game to improve my coding skills. I've read that by default JPanel will be double buffered and so I thought I shouldn't have any problems with choppy movement if i just used a JPanel as my "Canvas". Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. Usually the players movement is super smooth, but on seemingly random occasions it becomes extremely choppy. I tried capping the fps, but that didn't make a difference. I've also tried creating a Buffer Strategy myself, which also didn't get rid of the problem. As suggested by a comment (thank you!) here is a minimalistic version which just displays the problem:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    final static private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    static private Window gameWindow = new Window();
    final static private GameLoop gameLoop = new GameLoop();
    final static private Player player = new Player();

    //getters/(setters)
    public static Canvas canvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public static Window gameWindow() {
        return gameWindow;
    }

    public static Player player() {
        return player;
    }

    public static GameLoop gameLoop() {
        return gameLoop;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        gameWindow().makeWindow(false);
        gameLoop().startLoop(60.0);
        gameWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GameLoop {

    private boolean gameIsRunning = true;
    private double tps = 0;

    public void startLoop(double ticksps){
        tps = ticksps;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loop();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loop() {
        //stolen from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/52841/the-most-efficient-and-accurate-game-loop
        //and edited slightly for fps capping by using sleep
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double ns = 1000000000 / tps;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        long lastTimePainted = 0;
        int ticks = 0;
        long now = 0;
        int timeToNextFrame = 0;
        while(gameIsRunning) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                ticks++;
                updateGame();
                delta--;
            }
            if (System.nanoTime() - lastTimePainted > 3000000) {
                frames++;
                Main.canvas().repaint();
                lastTimePainted = System.nanoTime();
            }
            else {
                timeToNextFrame = (int) (3000000 - (System.nanoTime() - lastTimePainted));
                //System.out.println(timeToNextFrame);
                try {
                    if (timeToNextFrame > 1999998) {
                        Thread.sleep(0, 999999);
                    }
                    else if (timeToNextFrame > 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(0, timeToNextFrame / 2);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                System.out.println(frames + " " + ticks);
                ticks = 0;
                frames = 0;
                timer += 1000;
            }
          }
    }

    private void updateGame() {
        Main.player().move();   
    }
}

class Player{

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int velX = 2;
    private int velY = 2;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + 50 >= Main.gameWindow().getWidth() || x < 0) {
            velX = -velX;
        }
        if (y + 50 >= Main.gameWindow().getHeight() || y < 0) {
            velY = -velY;
        }
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void makeWindow (boolean fullscreen) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Game Prototype");
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().add(Main.canvas());
        Main.canvas().setLocation(0, 0);
        setFocusable(true);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        setSize(1024, 576);
        Main.canvas().setSize(1024, 576);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Canvas(){
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(Main.player().getX(), Main.player().getY(), 50, 50);
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Because i just kind of copy pasted this out of my code to work there might be some useless leftover out of the full code.

Comment: Never call dispose() on a Graphics object which you didn’t create.  In particular, the Graphics object passed to painting methods is created by Swing, and owned by Swing, and may well be used for painting other things.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, i did as you said.

Comment: 1st thing I'd recommend is replacing the game loop with a Swing `Timer` set to fire every second.